# is there any way to access web server databases by android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, web

i want to access to my web mysql databases from android application.how can i do this?
i have searched all over the internet but i didnt get anything like that.
allthough i know how to recieve data from the web pages as json data.but i need something like i can acces the database directly like the web applications.

such as i have an existing database where i want to acces from the mobile or i have a database on a server i want to keep my data in the web how can i do this?
i can receive the json data from the server but i dont know how to use the database directly.
if any tutorial it would be nice.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a socket and connect using TCP like the post here:

[Android client and Java server TCP communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073473/android-client-and-java-server-tcp-communication)

Then you can connect using DriverManager:

[input data into android database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116220/input-data-into-android-database)

Most projects are not worth the overhead. Using JSON is probably easier...

Comment: Easier and safer.  It is generally considered a serious security issue to have your database directly accessible on the internet.